# MVC hidden field being validated

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a few fields on my page that appear and dissappear depending on the dropdown selections you make on the page.

So, for example, I have

```
<section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuctionTypeId)
            <div> @Html.DropDownList("AuctionTypeId", Model.AuctionTypes, @AuctionControllerResource.SelectAuctionType, new { id="auctionType", required = "required" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuctionTypeId)       </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AutomaticExtensionType, new { hidden = "true", id = "automaticExtensionTypeLabel" })
            <div> @Html.DropDownList("AutomaticExtensionType", Model.AutomaticExtensions, @AuctionControllerResource.SelectAutomaticExtensionType, new { hidden="hidden", required = "required", id = "automaticExtensionTypeList" }) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AutomaticExtensionType)       </div>
        </section>
```

The JQuery code I have for this is

```
$('#auctionType').change(function () {
    var selectedAuctionType = $("#auctionType").val();
    var englishAuctionType = $("#englishAuctionTypeId").val();
    if (selectedAuctionType == englishAuctionType) {
        $("#automaticExtensionTypeList").show();
        $("#automaticExtensionTypeLabel").show();
    } else {
        $("#automaticExtensionTypeList").hide();
        $("#automaticExtensionTypeLabel").hide();
    }
});
```

Now, the showing and hiding work like they should.  The problem is that when I submit the form and the field `automaticExtensionTypeList` is hidden, the form doesn't submit because `automaticExtensionTypeList` is a required field.  The question is how can I tell MVC to only validate visible fields?

I've had a look through some of the JQuery we have written in this project and we have this line

```
$.validator.setDefaults({ ignore: [] });
```

Apparantly this enables hidden validation.  My question is, what line of code does the opposite?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: ':hidden, [readonly=readonly]'
});
```

or for customizes

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    ignore: "#automaticExtensionTypeList" 
});
```

Comment: Shall I add this to the view?

Comment: That's the thing - I don't want to replace it because actually it is in an external library (KendoUI) and may be used elsewhere.  What I do want to do is for my particular page override it.

Comment: The place where I am doing $("#automaticExtensionTypeList").show();, could I not also add or remove the required attribute at that place?

Comment: Don't quite know the syntax though - more of a C# than JQuery person.

Comment: Syntax should not change (Im more C# too, but been doin a lot of JQ lately. getn kinda comfy with it ;)

Comment: hmmm.  Is it $("#automaticExtensionTypeList").Remove("required");?

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that hidden fields are not designed for use when a field doesn't apply - they're designed for use when a field **does** apply but doesn't require input from the user. In your situation, you could:

- Use view logic to avoid rendering the field at all unless it is
  applicable.
- Use a **[custom validator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation.aspx)** instead of just a flat-out `Required`.
- Use a valid 'default' value in the hidden field.

Personally, I'd go for the last as it'll be quickest to implement and doesn't have any obvious pitfalls - you can pick up this default value in your controller and then manipulate it as needed.

Comment: wise beyond your years. Yes, all your approaches would work. They could all use a little more detail...

Answer (score 4):

This is a common problem.

Hiddens will not stop validation.

I always handle this by creating a multiple forms with overlapping properties.

**example:**

```
<div id="HasControlls">
@Using(Html.BeginForm)
{
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuctionTypeId)
            @Html.DropDownList("AuctionTypeId", Model.AuctionTypes, @AuctionControllerResource.SelectAuctionType, new { id="auctionType", required = "required" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuctionTypeId)       </div>
        </section>
        <section>
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AutomaticExtensionType, new { hidden = "true", id = "automaticExtensionTypeLabel" })
            <div> @Html.DropDownList("AutomaticExtensionType", Model.AutomaticExtensions, @AuctionControllerResource.SelectAutomaticExtensionType, new { hidden="hidden", required = "required", id = "automaticExtensionTypeList" }) 
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AutomaticExtensionType)       </div>
}



<div id="HasNotControlls">
@Using(Html.BeginForm)
{
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.AuctionTypeId)
            @Html.DropDownList("AuctionTypeId", Model.AuctionTypes, @AuctionControllerResource.SelectAuctionType, new { id="auctionType", required = "required" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AuctionTypeId)       </div>
        </section>
        <section>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AutomaticExtensionType)       </div>
        </section>
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, could you elaborate?

Comment: I would use 2 divs with completely distinct Forms. This way when I show/hide either I don't end up with pesky hidden [required]'s that stop my form submission