# Don't validate hidden field

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have some fields that are shown only depending on some conditions, it work's fine to show and hide field with Jquery

but these fields are validated on submit even if they are hidden, I have required in the model

how I can't validate the hidden fields ?? I found : http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/
or I can apply the following [MVC hidden field being validated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15313420/mvc-hidden-field-being-validated)

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want the field to be validated, then why POST the value at all? You can use a field in the model without having it be submitted as form data.

Comment: the `[disabled]` attribute will prevent form fields from being submitted in the default `<form>` submission behavior.

Comment: @Dismissile : because the Value is shown when a condition is true

Comment: zzzzBov : Do you mean add : Html.DropDownListFor(m=m.Types, Model.Types, new { @disabled = "disabled" }) ?

Answer (score 0):

you can change the input name attribute when you are hiding/showing it.
That way the it would be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

When you are doing your validation, add a condition:

```
if($("#myHiddenElement").css("display")!="none")
```